# iOS app for installing to remote device using UDID Build Error

Tags: iphone

Hi I am not new to titanium but i am new in creating the ipa using the titanium.The problem is that when i provide the provisioning file to the titnaium it start to build but it gives the following error

```
 ERROR] [DEBUG] While reading /Users/aadilf/Desktop/QLD Best Bets/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos/QLD Best Bets.app/images/icon.png pngcrush caught libpng error:
  [ERROR] [ERROR] While reading /Users/aadilf/Desktop/QLD Best Bets/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos/QLD Best Bets.app/images/icon.png pngcrush caught libpng error:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1477, in main
execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)
 File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1231, in execute_xcode
output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
 File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/iphone/run.py", line 41, in run
sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving the clean build to the project and run it again has solved the problem

Thanks